# XSL-transformation gives different results when interchange two identical lines

Tags: java, xslt, svg

I am trying to merge to svg file in one. I have got two files, "bg.svg":

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        version="1.1"
        width="500"
        height="500"
        xml:space="preserve">

    <g>
        <circle cy="250px" cx="250px" r="200" style="fill:black"></circle>
        <circle cy="250px" cx="250px" r="195" style="fill:white"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

and "arrow.svg":

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        version="1.1"
        width="500"
        height="500"
        id="arrow"
        xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="g10">
        <path d="M 250 245 L 250 255 L 400 255 L 400 265 L 415 250 L 400 235 L 400 245 L 250 245 " style="fill:red;stroke:#500;"></path>
    </g>
</svg>.
```

Then, I am trying to merge it with following XSL template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">


    <xsl:variable name="bg-doc" select="document('bg.svg')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/svg:svg">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./@*|./node()" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$bg-doc/svg:svg/svg:g" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... by this Java-code:

```java
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer( new StreamSource( new File("merge.xsl" ) ) );
transformer.transform( new StreamSource( new File("arrow.svg") ),
                           new StreamResult( new File("out.svg") ) );
```

This transformation have correct result:

```xml
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="500" height="500" id="arrow" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="g10">
        <path d="M 250 245 L 250 255 L 400 255 L 400 265 L 415 250 L 400 235 L 400 245 L 250 245 "
              style="fill:red;stroke:#500;"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <circle cy="250px" cx="250px" r="200" style="fill:black"/>
        <circle cy="250px" cx="250px" r="195" style="fill:white"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

But, when I am trying to change order of 11 and 12 lines of XSL template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">


    <xsl:variable name="bg-doc" select="document('bg.svg')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/svg:svg">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$bg-doc/svg:svg/svg:g" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./@*|./node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... transformation returns strange (non-valid) XML:

```xml
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <circle cy="250px" cx="250px" r="200" style="fill:black"/>
        <circle cy="250px" cx="250px" r="195" style="fill:white"/>
    </g>
    <svg version="1.1" width="500" height="500" id="arrow" xml:space="preserve">
        <g id="g10">
            <path d="M 250 245 L 250 255 L 400 255 L 400 265 L 415 250 L 400 235 L 400 245 L 250 245 "
                  style="fill:red;stroke:#500;"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Any ideas why it can happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, when I am trying to change order of 11 and 12 lines of XSL
> template:
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="/svg:svg"> 
>     <xsl:copy> 
>         <xsl:apply-templates select="$bg-doc/svg:svg/svg:g" /> 
>         <xsl:apply-templates select="./@*|./node()" /> 
>     </xsl:copy> 
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> transformation returns strange (non-valid) XML

This is exactly what you have specified with the swap of the two lines of code: first an `svg:g` element is copied from one of the SVG documents, then-only the attributes of the top element and the whole remaining SVG document is copied.

**Solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="bg-doc" select=
    "document('file:///c:/temp/delete/bg.svg')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/svg:svg">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$bg-doc/svg:svg/svg:g" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (`arrow.svg`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        version="1.1"
        width="500"
        height="500"
        id="arrow"
        xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="g10">
        <path d="M 250 245 L 250 255 L 400 255 L 400 265 L 415 250 L 400 235 L 400 245 L 250 245 " style="fill:red;stroke:#500;"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**and the provided second document** (`bg.svg`) at `c:\temp\delete\`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        version="1.1"
        width="500"
        height="500"
        xml:space="preserve">

    <g>
        <circle cy="250px" cx="250px" r="200" style="fill:black"></circle>
        <circle cy="250px" cx="250px" r="195" style="fill:white"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**a correct result is now produced**:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="500" height="500" id="arrow" xml:space="preserve"><g>
        <circle cy="250px" cx="250px" r="200" style="fill:black"/>
        <circle cy="250px" cx="250px" r="195" style="fill:white"/>
    </g>
    <g id="g10">
        <path d="M 250 245 L 250 255 L 400 255 L 400 265 L 415 250 L 400 235 L 400 245 L 250 245 " style="fill:red;stroke:#500;"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**Explanation**: Copying the attributes of an element must follow immediately the `xsl:copy` instruction for this element. Placing it after copying other elements leads to placing these attributes on the last copied element, not on the original owner of the attributes.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, I completely forgot about attributes!